# Firebase error "Security Rules Error - specified security rules file does not exist"

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

When attempting to deploy a firebase to their hosting service. I'm also using the `firebase` tool to publish security rules. I see this error message:

```
$  firebase deploy
Security Rules Error - specified security rules file does not exist
```

But, I do have security rules specified. Here is my `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "firebase": "example-firebase",
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

What's wrong with how I specified my security rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security rules must be specified in a second file that you refer to from `firebase.json`. Here's how you should rearrange your configuration files to work with the `firebase deploy` command.

**./firebase.json**:

```
{
  "firebase": "example-firebase",
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rules": "firebase-security-rules.json"
}
```

**./firebase-security-rules.json**:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

For more details see the [Advanced Configuration section](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html#section-advanced-properties) of the Firebase Hosting docs.

Comment: This syntax didn't work for me, please see my answer here